# Кроссбраузерность в internet explorer/edge

Tags: html, css

Есть меню, которое выровнено по вертикали и горизонтали, делал в chrome, все отображается как надо, но в internet explorer и edge это меню сдвигается по вертикали на 1px вниз, в чём проблема?

```css
.section {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: #aeaeae;
  text-align: center;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
}

ul a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  padding: 27px 25px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="section">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Abou us</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Products</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Maps</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Так выглядит в chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
internet explorer/edge

Comment: Как минимум вы не прописали высоту в меню, и она будет вычисляться автоматически на усмотрение браузера. В мобильном Chrome тоже всё торчит.

Comment: в FF тоже торчит : https://prnt.sc/sd2kbn

Comment: Вообще, манипулировать высотой inline-элементов не очень хорошая идея, они весьма негибкие в этом плане. С inline-block проблем меньше, с flex ещё меньше

Comment: Предлогаете задать отступы элементам li ?

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/VwvXMOm - вот так вылазиет ?